# how to show the direction from current location to destination location in map in iphone

Tags: iphone, google-maps, sqlite, core-location, latitude-longitude

In my application first i am finding the current location using corelocation framework, and stored some values of latitudes and longitudes in sqlite3 and displaying the corresponding names of  those latitudes and longitudes in the tableview which are within 100 meters or 200 meters depending upon the user distance selection, if i have given 100 meters it will show some names in the table view, on click of any name in the table view i need to show the google map of direction from current location to the selected name which has some corresponding latitude and longitude.how to achieve this, is there any link or url, so that i can get a clear idea to develop this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open this url in `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:]` method

http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=lat,long&daddr=lat,long

you can pass lat/long info or actual address as the saddr and daddr parameters.

Comment: I need to show only the Map, i tried using the format you said, it shows only the direction in the form of walking direction, bus route only, instead of this i need to show only the google Map.

Comment: how to get only the map directly without any other information.i get the map on click of some button.